# Google Compute Engine (GCE) email delivery solution other than sendgrid?

Tags: email, google-compute-engine

Need transaction email support for e-commerce server hosted in GCE. Sendgrid was the only option, but they rejected our request stating our business doesn't comply with their terms and conditions. Do we have any other option now to continue in google cloud.

Thanks

Comment: This restriction in Google Compute Engine forced us look for other cloud operators.

Answer (score 3):

There are several transactional email platforms. The most popular i know are the following:

- [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)
- [Mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com)
- [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com)
- [Mandrill](http://www.mandrill.com)

All of then provide SMTP interface to send emails like [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com). Although i havent tested them with gce i believe all of them will work.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone tried MailJet from Google Compute Engine instances?

Sounds like I can't access in-v3.mailjet.com from a GCE instance:

```
$ telnet in-v3.mailjet.com 25
Trying 178.32.115.14...

$ telnet in-v3.mailjet.com 587
Trying 178.32.115.14...
```

From my laptop, it works:

```
$ telnet in-v3.mailjet.com 25
Trying 37.59.74.234...
Connected to in.mailjet.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 leela-8.mailjet.com ESMTP Mailjet
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ telnet in-v3.mailjet.com 587
Trying 37.59.74.234...
Connected to in.mailjet.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 leela-9.mailjet.com ESMTP Mailjet
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I also tried using the same IP address I got on my laptop `37.59.74.234` instead of `in-v3.mailjet.com` but no luck.

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/) it's not that easy. You can only:

- use SendGrid for sending email
- use a Google Apps domain